# Android remove duplicate user permission in manifest file

Tags: android, permissions

I have this android project with a intricate manifest file that specify a lot of user permission, but many of them are duplicate. Probably caused by copy and paste.
I wonder if there a quick way to remove all the duplicate permissions.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: There aren't actually very many permissions in Android - how can it be so difficult to just edit it by hand? Post the manifest.

Comment: So I just clear the permissions and add them by myself..

Comment: `grep uses-permission AndroidManifest.xml | sort -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin to remove duplicate lines in manifest.xml file. This is a String manipulation file to remove duplicate lines. Hope this will helps you.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162